# Keylistener registers 1 second later

Tags: java, linux, keylistener, chromebook, crouton

A keylistener that I put on a jframe is delaying around 1 second, when it should be near instant. I'm fairly certain this is a linux/crouton issue, because the code works fine on a windows system.

```
public void initComponents(){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
  frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
      System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    }
  })

  frame.setSize(500, 300);
  frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: The first event when you press a key should occur immediately. If you hold down a key then the repeat rate is controlled by the OS. Search the web for the Linux repeat rate. Maybe this link will get your started: http://linuxforcynics.com/how-to/set-keyboard-repeat-delay-and-rate

Comment: It's not repeat rate, it's the actual key events that are delayed when I press a key on my keyboard by approx 1 second.